# How do I get Boto to return EC2 instances - S3 works fine

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I'm having some issues with the EC2 bit of Boto (Boto v2.8.0, Python v2.6.7).

The first command returns a list of S3 Buckets - all good! The second command to get a list of EC2 instances blows up with a 403 with "Query-string authentication requires the Signature, Expires and AWSAccessKeyId parameters"

```
s3_conn = S3Connection(AWSAccessKeyId, AWSSecretKey)
print s3_conn.get_all_buckets()

ec2_conn = EC2Connection(AWSAccessKeyId, AWSSecretKey)
print ec2_conn.get_all_instances()
```

Also, my credentials are all good (Full admin) - I tested them using the Ruby aws-sdk, both EC2 and S3 work fine.

I also noticed that the **host** attribute in the ec2_conn object is **s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com**, "s3"...? Surely thats wrong? I've tried retro fixing it to the correct endpoint but no luck.

Any help would be great appreciate
Thanks

Comment: I looked at Boto [source code](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/2.8.0/boto/ec2/__init__.py#L42) and  there is no reference to s3 there.

Comment: The same applies [here](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/2.8.0/boto/ec2/connection.py#L71).

Comment: I've figured it out (well I found the issue) - I'm developing this on my Mac which I have Python2.6 installed. Tried it on one of my CentOS 6 boxes - works perfectly. The issue is my Mac. Still, strange how the S3 command works, yet the EC2 request gets a 403...

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. I work with boto on a Mac all the time.  And Python 2.6 is not an issue.  I think there is some other underlying issue with your configuration or your credentials.  Also, I would use the connect_to_region() method to actually create the connection to the services.

Comment: So you have two Pythons and two Botos or what? I used to notice that all the time with my Windows with 4 different Pythons.

Answer (score 6):

Here's some working code I use to list all my instances across potentially multiple regions. 
Its doing a lot more than you need, but maybe you can pare it down to what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto
import boto.ec2
import sys

class ansi_color:
  red   = '\033[31m'
  green = '\033[32m'
  reset = '\033[0m'
  grey  = '\033[1;30m'


def name(i):
  if 'Name' in i.tags:
    n = i.tags['Name']
  else:
    n = '???'
  n = n.ljust(16)[:16]
  if i.state == 'running':
    n = ansi_color.green + n + ansi_color.reset
  else:
    n = ansi_color.red + n + ansi_color.reset
  return n

def pub_dns( i ):
  return i.public_dns_name.rjust(43)

def pri_dns( i ):
  return i.private_dns_name.rjust(43)

def print_instance( i ):
  print '  ' + name(i) + '| ' + pub_dns(i) + ' ' + pri_dns(i)


regions = sys.argv[1:]
if len(regions)==0:
  regions=['us-east-1']

if len(regions)==1 and regions[0]=="all":
  rr = boto.ec2.regions()
else:
  rr = [ boto.ec2.get_region(x) for x in regions ]

for reg in rr:
  print "========"
  print reg.name
  print "========"
  conn = reg.connect()

  reservations = conn.get_all_instances()

  for r in reservations:
  #  print ansi_color.grey + str(r) + ansi_color.reset
    for i in r.instances:
      print_instance(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is the connect_to_region command:

```
import boto.ec2

connection = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('eu-west-1', aws_access_key_id=AWSAccessKeyId,
                                        aws_secret_access_key=AWSSecretKey)
```

The [Boto tutorial](http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/ec2_tut.html#a-note-about-regions) gives another way. That method would basically work like this:

```
import boto.ec2

for region in boto.ec2.regions():
    if region.name == 'my-favorite-region':
        connection = region.connect()
        break
```

This has not been working on [older versions](https://code.google.com/p/boto/issues/detail?id=232) of Boto.

Comment: Hi ferrix, thanks for replying - I've tried the connect_to_region command - same error 403. And the boto.ec2.regions() to grab the right one, but the host always seems to go to "s3-...", which may be a red herring..?

Comment: Have you tried specifying your own endpoint in boto configuration?

Comment: Your first example is really the best way to get a connection object.  I'll update the tutorial to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your IAM credentials in order? The given access key should have rights for EC2. If you're not sure, you can add the policy AmazonEC2FullAccess to test, and later tune this down.